# A condition with multiple commands

Tags: command-line, bash

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
if
rsync $folder/coopshop/prod $folder2/coopshop
rsync $folder/coopweb/prod $folder2/coopweb
rsync $folder/unihobbyshop/shop $folder2/unihobbyshop
rsync $folder/unnihobbyweb/web $folder2/unihobbyweb
then
  echo "OK! rsync done!"
else
  echo "Error! rsync crashed!"
fi
```

I know there is a possibility to do with `\` character at the end of the line, but this is not quite an elegant solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/running-multiple-commands-in-one-line-in-shell

Comment: Did you search a bit for yourself on how bash scripting works?

Comment: Exactly what behavior do you want? If one of the `rsync` command fails, do you want it to run the rest, or stop on the failure? Also, if some of the `rsync`s succeed and some fail, should it print "OK" or "Error"?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Hello, in case of one command is false, then message would be false. I think this is possible to do with commands in variable **command=$(commands)** divided by enter, and simply with **if($commands)**. I will test and let you know.

Comment: your example doesn't have the condition part right.. it just runs the rsync commands.. or is a pseudocode?

Comment: A backslash before the end of the line won’t help in your case. It’s used to continue the _same_ command on the next line but in your case, there is _another_ `rsync` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Consider `set -e`.

If this is in a script, then you'll probably want to remove the `if`...`then` entirely and just put `set -e` at the top of the script. This causes the script to stop immediately if any command fails. When any of those `rsync` commands fail, they'll display error messages explaining the failure, so you probably don't need to write your own message at all.

If you want to show the commands that are run before running them, use `set -x`. You can combine the two by writing `set -ex`.

#### With `&&`, you don't need `\`.

If you do decide to write something along the lines of what you've shown, then [as Ronny Blomme says](https://askubuntu.com/a/1154686/22949) you can separate the commands with `&&`. Note that you don't need to run the commands in [subshells](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), i.e., you *don't* need to enclose them in [parentheses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping).

If you write an `&&` operator at the end of a line, then you don't need to write `\` to specify line continuation. A command can't end in `&&` (logical *AND*) or `||` (logical *OR*) so the shell will continue parsing onto the next line.

```bash
if
    rsync "$folder/coopshop/prod" "$folder2/coopshop" &&
    rsync "$folder/coopweb/prod" "$folder2/coopweb" &&
    rsync "$folder/unihobbyshop/shop" "$folder2/unihobbyshop" &&
    rsync "$folder/unnihobbyweb/web" "$folder2/unihobbyweb"
then
    echo 'OK! rsync commands completed successfully!'
else
    echo 'Error! some rsync command failed!'
fi
```

You don't have to put `&&` at the end of a line. You can write multiple commands on the same line separated by `&&` if you like.

Note that the final command being tested doesn't end with `&&` because `&&` *separates* the commands. If any command fails, the others will not run.

#### Running all the commands even if some of them fail

You may instead want to run all the `rsync` commands even if some of them fail, then test if *any* of them failed and operate accordingly. For this, you can trap `ERR`. This is not an actual signal, but the `ERR` signal_spec in bash catches commands that fail for any reason, including a crash (and including SIGINT). See [pLumo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155173/22949) (but omit `set -e` to keep going) and [this post by William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42219754/1038860); for more general information, see the output of `help trap`.

The way I like to do it (with commands like yours plugged in) is:

```bash
failed=
trap 'failed=yes' ERR

rsync "$folder/coopshop/prod" "$folder2/coopshop"
rsync "$folder/coopweb/prod" "$folder2/coopweb"
rsync "$folder/unihobbyshop/shop" "$folder2/unihobbyshop"
rsync "$folder/unnihobbyweb/web" "$folder2/unihobbyweb"

if [ -z "$failed" ]; then
    echo 'OK! rsync commands completed successfully!'
else
    echo 'Error! some rsync command failed!'
fi
```

#### About the other changes I've made... and what `if command` really tests.

Your arguments to `rsync` use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) so I've taken the liberty of [double-quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) them. Otherwise, [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) will be performed. From context it appears you don't want those additional expansions. ([Usually you don't.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells))

Note that, contrary to the message your script prints, you are not actually testing if any `rsync` command *crashed*. You are instead testing if any `rsync` command *failed*. Crashing is abnormal program termination, where a process is terminated by a signal, typically due to a bug or a condition that cannot be reasonably handled. This is far rarer than normal program termination, which may itself occur with an exit status indicating *success* (zero) or *failure* (some other number). If `rsync` *does* crash, the code above *will* catch that too. But most of what it's catching, in practice, is normal program termination with an exit status indicating failure.

Comment: I like the use of trap without exit on error. Never thought about it :-) I would have used `rsync ... || failed=yes`, but the trap is much more elegant.

Comment: "if/then/else" feels too much like something other than bash.  You might also consider syntax like: ``[ -z $failed ]  &&  echo "OK"  ||  echo "Error"``.

Comment: @RayButterworth `if` is commonly used in bash and shouldn't be feared. [You might consider *not* using `a && b || c` as a ternary conditional, as it's wrong.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015) Even `echo` can fail in a write error, like with `>/dev/full`; it can even happen unexpectedly. Even when `b` can't fail, testing it expresses the wrong idea. I do consider `&&` and `||` when I write single-branch `if`s. `a && b` for `if a; then b; fi`, and `a || b` for `if ! a; then b; fi`, are often reasonable, albeit not completely equivalent (`if` succeeds when its condition fails).

Answer (score 4):

For a script like yours, I would not use `if`/`else`, but enable *exit on error* (`set -e`) and trapping.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail
trap 'echo "Error! rsync crashed!"' ERR INT

rsync $folder/coopshop/prod $folder2/coopshop
rsync $folder/coopweb/prod $folder2/coopweb
rsync $folder/unihobbyshop/shop $folder2/unihobbyshop
rsync $folder/unnihobbyweb/web $folder2/unihobbyweb

echo "OK! rsync done!"
```

Comment: Is it necessary to list `INT`? I believe `ERR` covers all cases in which the shell detects abnormal program termination, in addition to cases of normal program termination that causes a command to have nonzero exit status. (I've tested this by running `trap 'echo "trap triggered"' ERR` followed by a couple runs of `sleep 10` during which I send the `sleep` process SIGINT. Whether SIGINT is sent by pressing Ctrl+C on the terminal or with `killall -INT sleep` on another terminal, the message is printed.)

Comment: maybe right, I didn't test, see also "Something like this"^^, so deviations are allowed, and you give a good one in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

try this syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir dir1 dir2
echo "test1" > dir1/file1
echo "test2" > dir1/file2

if (rsync dir1/file1 dir2) && (rsync dir1/file2 dir2) 
then
  echo "OK! rsync done!"
else
  echo "Error! rsync crashed!"
fi
```

Comment: Much better **Ronny! +1** from me (cc @Melebius )  **;-)**